# How to add a text to HTML page from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `textarea` in HTML page (`page.html`) and it has JavaScript in it, so what I want is, through JavaScript I could add the text in another HTML page (`page2.html`) written in the `textarea` of `page1.html`. How can it be done?

Comment: Have you done any work around this? If yes, can you add them here?

Comment: Try adding the value to the query string then access that string on the other page

Comment: Examples [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must first create a new text node. This statement creates a new text node with the text "this is a test":

```
var node=document.createTextNode("this is a test");
```

Next, you can add this node to the document. To do this, you use the `appendChild` method. The text can be added to any element that can contain text, but we will use a paragraph. The following statement adds the text node defined above to the paragraph with the identifier `p1`:

```
document.getElementById("p1").appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of back-end. `page.html` sends ajax request to backend with updated value, `page2.html` sends ajax request to backend to get that value. If you don't know any back-end language (node.js, php for example), it will be hard to achieve this.

Another case if for example `page2.html` is "iframed" into `page.html`, then you can access directly with Javascript.